# Equivalent SqlFunction.Difference in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a code in EF6 and would like to translate it to EF Core. What equivalent SqlFunction.Difference in EF Core?

```
  public virtual IEnumerable<Role> GetSimilarRoles(string soundsLike)
  {
            return Get(x =>  SqlFunctions.Difference(x.Name, soundsLike) >= 3, q => q.OrderBy(o => o.Name));
  }
```

Comment: That's a pretty ... "limited" function for fuzzy matching or even phonetic matching for non-English speakers. Worse, it can't be accelerated by an index. What are you using it for? Full text search may be a better option, while the R and Python support in SQL Server 2016 and later allows you to use powerful fuzzy matching libraries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no out of the box equivalent in EF Core.

But it can easily be added using the EF Core 2.0+ [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping), e.g.

```
public static class SqlFunctions
{
    [DbFunction("DIFFERENCE", "")]
    public static int? Difference(string s1, string s2)
        => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Fluent configuration (required for functions which are not exposed through `DbContext` derived class):

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(() => SqlFunctions.Difference(default, default));
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is an equivalent avaialble, however EF Core has functions via **`EF.Functions`**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbfunctions?view=efcore-3.0

```
public static bool Like (this Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbFunctions _, string matchExpression, string pattern);
```